# How can I center my textView in the middle of my ImageView?

Tags: android, textview, imageview, center, gravity

I want to center vertical and horizontal my textView. Now I have the textView in the left corner of my imageView. Thanks a lot

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_weight="3" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/numero" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_numero"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use the android:layout_centerInParent="true", since your ImageView seems to take up your entire layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `RelativeLayout` it's easy!

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_numero"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

By the way, it's not necessary to make use of `android:layout_weight` when using `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your textview

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```